# Company Communities User

Tags: community

I need to get to know whether we can create Work Order using 
Company Communities User license type or not? If yes then how?
The access permission for CRUD is already enable still i can't able to create new Work Order.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine the solution would be:

- Enable Work Orders under `Setup | Field Service | Settings`
- Make the Work Orders tab [visible in the Employee Apps Community](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063000000045WzAAI) (Company Community = Employee Apps and Community)

[image]